# Mysql query issues when passing string or date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query that works fine in phpmyadmin, but does not give the expected results on my php page.  I am sure that I have something wrong in the code.

Here is the php code that passes the **variable**

```
print "<td><a href='transactions_by_transaction_date.php?var=\''".urlencode(
$row['transaction_date'])."'\''>".$row['transaction_date']."</a></td></tr><tr>";
```

And here is where I create my query

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
echo $var;
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM bo_transactions WHERE 
transaction_date=:var ORDER BY transaction_id");
$stmt2->bindParam(':var',$var,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->execute();
// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I have the `echo $var` line to verify that it is passing the correct date and it appears to be.  The field transaction_date is a date type.

What have I missed?

Comment: What result does it outputs? What is structure of DB?

Comment: That opening snippet of html/php is incorrectly quoted by the looks of things - probably moer like `print "<td><a href='transactions_by_transaction_date.php?var=".urlencode($row['transaction_date'])."'>".$row['transaction_date']."</a></td></tr><tr>";`

Comment: here `print "<td><a href=\"transactions_by_transaction_date.php?var=".urlencode($row['transaction_date'])."\">".$row['transaction_date']."></a></td></tr><tr>";`

Comment: Table  structure`code`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bo_transactions` (
  `transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_date` date NOT NULL,
  `customer_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `account_num` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `bill_amount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `bill_date` date NOT NULL,
  `pay_amount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `pay_date` date NOT NULL,
  `last_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT

Comment: The variable is passed, however the query returns no values

Answer (score 1):

I thing you have issue in **single quotes** and **double quotes** data passing

Just use this one

```
print "<td><a href='transactions_by_transaction_date.php?var='".urlencode($‌​
row['transaction_dat‌​e'])."'>".$row['tran‌​saction_date']."</a>‌​</td></tr><tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

My apologies to everyone.  The problem was not in the code posted  it was a typing error in  my output.  Thank you to all that gave me input